# Copy image from sdcard to android project package

Tags: android, image, copy, package, sd-card

How can I copy an image from sdcard ("mnt/sdcard/pictures/pic.jpg") to the project package ("data/data/project_package"), also, is there a method which scales the image to a fixed size so that the copied image is a thumb-nail of the original

Comment: u can directly use image from sd card. why it is required to copy the image from sdcard to your package directory.

Comment: because I want a resized version of the picture, and if the user deletes the picture, then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless physical data size is on your priority list, you could leave the image alone and load it using createScaledBitmap

refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29